# AWS Elastic beanstalk i'm not able to access my JAVA api restfull application after deploy http 404 error

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, jersey, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i've deployed my java application on Amazon AWS Elastic beanstalk server, but i'm not able to access the endpoints, it's throwing 404 error, i've tried ping the IP, change path on my application.. everything, but i didn't succeed. can someone assist me?
FYI:the same WAR file is running perfectly on another server.

Thank you.

Comment: Q: Have you *EVER* successfully deployed?  If so, "what changed"?  Q: What do the server logs say?  Have you looked?  Q: Exactly what kind of "Java application"???  A Tomcat servlet?  SUGGESTION: Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post back.

Comment: Yes, it is deployed successfully, but the log says the attempts of access, but is showing error 404 there, this is a java application with jersey and hibernate, java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, the cause of the problem was that the filter for CORS (Allow-Control-Cross-Origin) in web.xml was blocking the application to be accessed, i don't know why, but i've deleted all the CORS configurations inside  tag, and the issue got resolved.